# ARKit allowsCameraControl

Tags: ios11, arkit

I'm implementing `allowsCameraControl` in my ARKit scene via an IBAction that sets `self.sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true` via a switch, it works great.  My switch logic seems fine in the debugger, however when I turn `self.sceneView.allowsCameraControl = false` - the camera doesn't return back to it's original tracking state.  The objects stay stationary in my Scene View.  Any clues?

Answer (score 6):

The allowsCameraControl option is defined by `ARSCNView`'s superclass `SCNView` — which is to say, it's designed for non-AR situations. That it behaves strangely in that view's ARKit subclass is probably a bug (arguably, it shouldn't work at all, since in AR the camera is supposed to always match device movement). You might want to [file that bug with Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com).

In the meantime, if you want to switch between AR (user controls camera by moving device) and non-AR (you control camera, or user controls camera via touch gestures) views of the same content, you might experiment with moving your scene between instances of `ARSCNView` and `SCNView`.